# Reject anonymous connection except for some url

Tags: symfony

I need to deny anonymous connections except for some url.

```
firewalls:
        install:
            pattern:    ^/install/.*
            security:  false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider:    fos_userbundle
                login_path:    /login
                check_path:    /login_check
                use_forward:    true
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path:            /
                post_only:    true
            logout:    true
            anonymous:    ~

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_check, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/install/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

It sounds like the line "- { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_USER }" does the job, but override my firewall "Install" cause they share the same root (pattern /).

How can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick way would be to exclude the `/install` path from your `main` firewall:

```
firewalls:
        install:
            pattern:    ^/install/.*
            security:  false
        main:
            pattern: ^/(?!install/)
            ...
```